# Removing "" in concatenated string

Tags: python, locust

In my Locust/Python script I have a function (*get_ts_ids*) like this:

```
def _get_ts_ids():
    csv_file = os.path.join("C:", os.sep, "PythonScripting", "MyCode", "pythonProject", "TS_ID.csv")

    with open(csv_file) as csvfile:
        field_names = ["TS_ID"]
        dr = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=field_names)
        ts_ids_all = [row["TS_ID"] for row in dr]
        shuffle(ts_ids_all)  # RANDOMIZE LIST OF VALUES
        ts_ids_head = ts_ids_all[0:10]  # SELECT FIRST x ITEMS
        print(ts_ids_head)
        return ",".join(ts_ids_head)  # CONCATENATE VALUES
```

I am using the test data in constructing a json like this:

```
def get_data():
    myjson = {
        "tsIds": [
            _get_ts_ids()
        ],
        "resolution": "PT15M",
        "startUtc": "2023-12-07T14:55:18.626Z",
        "endUtc": "2023-12-07T14:55:18.626Z"
    }
    return myjson
```

The outcome is:

```
    {
    "tsIds": [
    "332157,333225,338380,315595,366277,324161,222850,247119,209902,354500"
    ],
    "resolution": "PT15M",
    "startUtc": "2023-12-07T14:55:18.626Z",
    "endUtc": "2023-12-07T14:55:18.626Z"
    }
```

It is all working as expected, however I want to remove the "" in the json being constructed. How can I strip the two "" of?

I want this to be the "output/result":

```
{
"tsIds": [
254692,
375565,
375451
],
"resolution": "PT15M",
"startUtc": "2023-12-07T14:55:18.626Z",
"endUtc": "2023-12-07T14:55:18.626Z"
}
```

The testdata file looks like this:

```
TS_ID
53005
246388
45032
243898
161700
```

Comment: If you remove `"` it's no longer json.

Comment: If you're trying to get `tsIds` to be treated as a `list` of `int`s, rather than a `list` with a single `str`, don't `join` the values to a string before `return`ing from `_get_ts_ids()`.

Comment: `return ts_ids_head` rather than `return ",".join(ts_ids_head)` if you are the only consumer of `_get_ts_ids()` otherwise `"tsIds": _get_ts_ids().split(","),`

Comment: I am a bit lost here. Can you clarify where exactly a double occurring "" appears, I am seeing none, or else clarify what one should see in the outcome you do not like.

Comment: @Daraan: "332157,333225,338380,315595,366277,324161,222850,247119,209902,354500"
],

Comment: seems "tsIds": _get_ts_ids().split(","), does still "produce": {
  "tsIds": [
    [
      "318622",
      "264187",
      "257598",
      "308381",
      "311515",
      "286210",
      "338176",
      "382963",
      "267699",
      "254742"
    ]
  ],
  "resolution": "PT15M",
  "startUtc": "2023-12-07T14:55:18.626Z",
  "endUtc": "2023-12-07T14:55:18.626Z"
}

Comment: Pleas include an example of the csv data you're reading that results in `[ [ "318622", "264187", "257598", "308381", "311515", "286210", "338176", "382963", "267699", "254742" ] ]`

Comment: the file looks like this:

TS_ID
53005
246388
45032
243898
161700

some are 6 numbers, some are 5. A problem?

Comment: Split on commas and convert to integers, then. `"123"` is a string, `123` is a number. The quotes won't be printed if you convert your data to be numbers. And the commas will be syntax instead of data if you split the string on commas into a list.

Comment: As a general rule, when dealing with formats that represent structured data, think about how to change the data to get your desired output -- **not** how to change the text that represents that data.

Comment: (and if you didn't concatenate everything into a single string in the first place, but appended to a list instead, you would have avoided the problem altogether)